# Levels of simple expressions

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to find and replace functions using the `x_[_]` pattern. However, I don't understand why these two very similar examples return different outputs.

**Case 1**

Input:

```
Cases[Cos[t] + 1, x_[_], Infinity]
Level[Cos[t] + 1, Infinity]
```

Output:

```
{Cos[t]}
{1, t, Cos[t]}
```

**Case 2**

Input:

```
Cases[Cos[t], x_[_], Infinity]
Level[Cos[t], Infinity]
```

Output:

```
{}
{t}
```

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use `{0, Infinity}` instead of `Infinity`

Comment: Yes, in that case, `Cases[Cos[t], x_[_], {0, Infinity}]` returns `{Cos[t]}`, which matches the output of `Cases[Cos[t] + 1, x_[_], Infinity]`. However, this does not explain the discrepancy between Case 1 and Case 2. Why is it that you must do that? (i.e. why `Cases[Cos[t], x_[_], 0]` returns `{}`?)

Comment: Look in the documentation, `Infinity` is equivalent to `{1, Infinity}`, not `{0, Infinity}`.

Comment: Right, but the only difference between `{1, Infinity}` and `Infinity` is `0`, and `0` does not return the expected output.

Comment: Use `{0}` instead of `0` if you just want to match the whole expression.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some comments on level specifications. The documentation lists the following possibilities:

$
\begin{array}{crl}
 \operatorname{      } & n & \text{levels 1 through $n$} \\
 \operatorname{      } & \operatorname{Infinity} & \text{levels 1 through $\operatorname{Infinity}$} \\
 \operatorname{      } & \operatorname{All} & \text{all levels, including zero} \\
 \operatorname{      } & \{n\} & \text{level $n$ only} \\
 \operatorname{      } & \left\{n_1,n_2\right\} & \text{levels $n_1$ through $n_2$} \\
\end{array}
$

So:

```
Cases[Cos[t], _[_], Infinity]
Level[Cos[t], Infinity]
```

> {}
>
> {t}

only look at levels `1` through `Infinity`. If you want to include levels `0` through `Infinity` you can do either:

```
Cases[Cos[t], _[_], All]
Level[Cos[t], All]
```

> {Cos[t]}
>
> {t, Cos[t]}

or

```
Cases[Cos[t], _[_], {0, Infinity}]
Level[Cos[t], {0, Infinity}]
```

> {Cos[t]}
>
> {t, Cos[t]}

Finally, if you want to look at just level `0`, you need to use:

```
Cases[Cos[t], _[_], {0}]
Level[Cos[t], {0}]
```

> {Cos[t]}
>
> {Cos[t]}

and not:

```
Cases[Cos[t], _[_], 0]
Level[Cos[t], 0]
```

> {}
>
> {}

This is because the level spec `0` looks at levels `1` through `0`, or in other words, *no* levels.